# Proving or disproving there exists a conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis

For each of the following regions, I need to give reasons why there can be no analytic function from $
\mathbb{C}$ one to-one onto that region. I am not allowed to use Picard's Theorem.

$$A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1 \}$$

$$B=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:\Re(z)>1\}$$

$$C=\mathbb{C} \setminus\{the \ non \ positive \ real \ axis \}$$

$$D=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$$

I would appreciate if anyone can correct my reasoning:

For $A$, I'm saying we cannot map an analytic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to this region because we cannot map $\infty$ one to one to $A$.

For B, we cannot map values such that $\Re(z)<1$ one to one to $B$.

For C, We cannot map values such that $\Re(z)>1$ one to one to $C$.

For $D$, I want to say yes because  $f(z)=1/z$ can make this work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $A$: You do not want to map $\infty$ anywhere, after all $\infty\notin \mathbb C$. However, if $f\colon\mathbb C\to A$ is ananlytic then it is a bounded entire function, hence constant (Liouville).
- $z\mapsto \frac2z-1$ shows that $B$ and $A$ are conformally equivalent, hence by the previous result, $B$ is not equivalent to $\mathbb C$
- $z\mapsto (z-1)^2$ shows that $B$ and $C$ are conformally equivalent, hence by the previous result, $C$ is not equivalent to $\mathbb C$
- $D$ is not simply connected, a property that is respected by conformal maps.

Comment: How is $A$ bounded? I don't understand how this proves one to one map

Comment: $A$ is the unit disc, so if $f$ is onto $A$, then $|f| < 1$, hence bounded.